# What's the best way to visualize hundreds of GPX files?

Tags: software-recommendations, gpx, mapping

I'm an amateur GIS enthusiast who maps my runs, hikes and urban explorations all over the place. I have accumulated hundreds of GPX files which I enjoy visualizing in different programs - but all of them fall short for one reason or another.

Googling just brings me to a lot of nonsense about interoperability between different run tracking programs and google maps.

Do any of you experts have a suggestion for a tool that will let me visualize all my GPX tracks in one world map? The closest thing I came across was umap but it had some annoying artifacts with certain files.

Comment: I think this would be better asked at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange because you are asking for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned if you want a "Web" map or a "Desktop" (downloadable, installed software) map. If you want web:

I'd recommend ArcGIS.com. You can create a personal account for free. You can use an email address, or sync with your google / facebook account. Once you've signed up with a free account you can add GPX files directly into a web map (drag/drop). Save the map, share it. You're done.

[Create a public account here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/createaccount.html)

More about adding GPX files [here](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/csv-gpx.htm). Note that adding GPX will add the trackpoints but also provide you with a line in the map. Based on this you can set the symbology size/color/other options on what makes the most sense.

*Note the free account does have some restrictions, but I didn't read anything that stands out as an impediment to what you'll be doing.

Comment: One limitation is the amount of features that can be served out with a free account.  This may be reached with longer routes with more waypoints.

Comment: Got a link? I just added a GPX with 3400 points and shows fine.

Comment: The "Add Layer from File" dialog in arcgis.com web map viewer states, "Locate the file you want to import. You can import up to 1000 features from a: [shapefile, csv, gpx]".  I just loaded 100K feature gpx file and it slowly worked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass on the message about the out of date message.

Comment: @artwork21 just curious: whats the memory footprint size of your browser with that 100k gpx?

Comment: around 2,000,000K

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using QGIS as the desktop viewer (free to use and install) and converting all the .gpx files into a GIS database (.sqlite, .gdb, or PostgresSQL/PostGIS).  You can apply spatial indexs on layer/tables within these database and they are great for handling big data.  Take a look at this [Q/A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130962/how-do-i-make-a-shp-file-from-waypoints), which will give you some basic info about converting .gpx files to shapefile.  Once you understand how to do this you could batch convert all your .gpx files stored in a directory using ogr2ogr command to any of the database formats noted above.