# How to number my GPS points sequentially?

Tags: qgis, gps, numbering

[image]

I want to number my GPS points from the first point to the final point,

the first point is 1,

second point is 2....

is there any plugin or toolbox I can use?

I used the plugin (sort and number),but show nothing

Comment: What software are you using? What spatial data format are you working with? Can you use OID or FID?

Comment: hi I'm using QGIS, The points are my gps data, I put them in QGIS,pardon my unclear expression, what is OID and FID

Comment: If you convert your points to shapefile format, they will automatically be numbered with an object ID in the "FID" field. More details here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130962/how-do-i-make-a-shp-file-from-waypoints

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field in QGIS in the attribute table as type integer.  Using the field calculator populate the file with the row number using $rownum.  Of course, this assumes that the points are stored in order in the attribute table in the same order as the points.
[Here is a link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41504/how-to-add-a-sequence-to-the-attribute-table) to more information.